# extracting link from text

Tags: ruby, regex

I am tring to extract a link from a phrase and it could be any where last, first or middle so I am usig this regex

```
link=text.scan(/(^| )(http.*)($| )/)
```

but the problem is when the link is in the middle it gets the whole phrase until the end. 
What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `.*` next to `http` is greedy. I suggest you to use lookarounds.

```
link=text.scan(/(?<!\S)(http\S+)(?!\S)/)
```

OR

```
link=text.scan(/(?<!\S)(http\S+)/)
```

Example:

```
> "http://bar.com foo http://bar.com bar http://bar.com".scan(/(?<!\S)http\S+(?!\S)/)
=> ["http://bar.com", "http://bar.com", "http://bar.com"]
```

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/uBguj1OipD)

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind which asserts that the match won't be preceeded by a non-space character.
- `http\S+` Matches the substring `http` plus the following one or more non-space characters.

Answer (score 0):

Do all the links you are trying to match follow some simple pattern? We'd need to see more context to confidently provide a good solution to your problem.

For example, the regex:

`link=text.scan(/http.*\.com/)`

...might be good enough for the job (this assumes all links end in ".com"), but I can't say for sure without more information.

Or again, for example, perhaps you could use something like:

`link=text.scan(/http[a-z./:]*)` - this assumes all links contain only lower case letters, ".", "/" and ":".